# Executing terminal command in different sessions with nodejs

Tags: node.js, child-process

I want to execute shell command with a nodejs script. And I have a problem about it

[As nodejs documentation says](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html);

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

This works great.

But what if I want to run a command which is kind a endless and I want to run another command.

For example;

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

    const simpleServer = spawn('python', ['-m', 'SimpleHTTPServer', '1234']);

    simpleServer.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    });

    simpleServer.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });

    simpleServer.on('close', (code) => {
      console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
    });

    gulper.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    });

    gulper.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });

    gulper.on('close', (code) => {
      console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
    });
```

Is there any way to do it with different sessions?

Comment: What problem are you facing with this code?

Comment: In second code, both is working but in the same session. I want to run them seperately. Like in different terminal screens. @Vasan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not run them seperately. You have to use Promise or a tool for async in NodeJS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Not my actual problem but you are right logically.